# Command "find" -exec replacing string

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, pdf

I'm trying to find JPG files in a folder tree to execute the command "" to transform it to PDF.

The problem is that the code I am running leaves the file in the same directory and I want to move it but preserve the structure of the tree of files.

What I've tried so far is:

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -exec mogrify -format pdf '{}' \;
```

This command works perfectly.
I want to manipulate "{}" shifting a portion of its content;

```
{} = ./1/aa.xxx
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
{} = ./new/1/aa.pdf
```

thanks to @mpez0 i can du little of changes an get a solution:

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' | while read file ; do 
oldfile=${file##*/};
olddir=${file/"$oldfile"/""};
pdfdir=${file/'./''./PDF'};
pdfdir=${pdfdir/"$oldfile"/""};
savedir=${file/'./''./OLD'};
savedir=${savedir/"$oldfile"/""};
newfile=${oldfile/.[Jj][Pp][Gg]/.pdf};
mogrify -format pdf "$file"; 
mkdir -p "$pdfdir";
mkdir -p "$savedir";
mv -- "$olddir$newfile" "$pdfdir$newfile"; 
mv -- "$olddir$oldfile" "$savedir$oldfile"; 
done
```

what this code do is: 
`find . -iname '*.jpg'` find all the files that end whit jpg and JPG 
`while read file ; do` if the action get ani file save the rout in the variable `file` 
`oldfile=${file##*/};` take out the file pat and save te name of the file in the variable `oldfile` 
`olddir=${file/"$oldfile"/""};` take out the name of the file to save the pat in `olddir` 
`pdfdir=${file/'./''./PDF'};` change ./ to ./pdf and save the new pat in `pdfdir` 
`pdfdir=${pdfdir/"$oldfile"/""};` take out the name of the file to save the pdf pat in `pdfdir` 
`savedir=${file/'./''./OLD'};` change ./ to ./old and save the new pat in `savedir` 
`savedir=${savedir/"$oldfile"/""};` take out the name of the file to save the pdf pat in `savedir` 
`newfile=${oldfile/.[Jj][Pp][Gg]/.pdf};` save the name of the new file that will be created in `newfile`
`mogrify -format pdf "$file";` convert the `file` to pdf 
`mkdir -p "$pdfdir";` create the directories of the pat `pdfdir` 
`mkdir -p "$savedir";` create the directories of the pat `savedir` 
`mv -- "$olddir$newfile" "$pdfdir$newfile";` move the new pdf file create to the pdf directorie
`mv -- "$olddir$oldfile" "$savedir$oldfile";` move the old jpg file to the old directorie
`done` end the proces

I hope this will help others

Comment: does mogrify have a -o flag for output location? would simplify code a bit.  also, what OS are you using? more specifically, what shell? With find, can we assume a Linux shell?

Comment: Rich, I'm using bash even in mac as in linux, no mogrify dosen't have it.

Comment: @AlejandroO'Byrne Please post the solution as an answer instead of editing body of your question(You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)). Even you can [accept the answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) too, which is worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' | while read f ; do 
    new=`echo $f | sed -e 's/\.[Jj][Pp][Gg]$/.pdf/'`; 
    newd=`dirname $f`;
    newd="new/$newd" 
    mogrify -format pdf $f; 
    mv $new $newd; 
done
```

Of course, I recommend running the script echoing the `mogrify` and `mv` commands. If `mogrify` offers an output option, use that instead of the mv. You may find it simpler to do a find and do all the `mogrify` transforms, then collect the new .pdfs.

Comment: thanks whit a little bit change i get the solution from your sugestion. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

If you use `convert` instead of `mogrify` (part of the same suite), your command then becomes:

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -exec convert -format pdf '{}' new/'{}'.pdf \;
```

Unlike `mogrify`, `convert` uses does not create an updated file extension, so you will get `.jpg.pdf` (plus capitalisation) as the new file extension, but that is easy to change with `rename`:

```
find new -iname '*.jpg.pdf' -exec rename 's/\.[Jj][Pp][Gg]//' '{}' \;
```

You can remove the JPEGs afterwards if you don't need to keep them (I hope you don't need *that* command spelling out).

Comment: this dosen't work

Comment: What doesn't work? I checked both commands with a single file in a temporary directory. Maybe the directory structure needs to be created in advance, using `find . -type d -exec mkdir new/'{}' \;`. Note that this will create directories even when there is no JPEG file in it. It would need to be a lot more complex to account for this, but you can always remove empty directories afterwards with `find new/ -type d -exec rmdir '{}' \;`.